# Should I move a binary used by a non-root user from /usr/bin/ to /usr/local/bin/?

Tags: rhel, directory-structure

I have gone through a related thread [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/308045/differences-between-bin-sbin-usr-bin-usr-sbin-usr-local-bin-usr-local).

A colleague of mine has copied the `phantomjs` binary to `/usr/bin`. In our system, this binary will be used only by a non-root user. At the moment, the regular user is able to run this binary fine, but going to the thread posted in this question, it does not like a right thing to put a binary used by a non-root user under `/usr/bin`. So is there any reason for me to move it from `/usr/bin` to `/usr/local/bin` or is it better to leave it at `/usr/bin`? In other words, would it make any difference to a binary if it is put under `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` or it is a 'rule' that is generally followed?

`[root@seco01 ~]# which phantomjs
/usr/bin/phantomjs
[root@seco01 ~]#`

P.S: `/usr/local/bin` is included in the `$PATH`.

Comment: Leave it in `/usr/local/bin`. Locally installed stuff should be in `/usr/local/bin`, not in `/usr/bin`, per the FHS.

Comment: That is what I had planned to do, but thought I will check here first to see if there is any other strong reason why it shouldn't be in `/usr/bin` since this binary is currently being used actively in some of our systems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Filesystem Hierarchy Standard says, per
[/usr/local : Local hierarchy](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_2.3/fhs-2.3.html#USRLOCALLOCALHIERARCHY), that

> The /usr/local hierarchy is for use by the system administrator when
>   installing software locally. It needs to be safe from being
>   overwritten when the system software is updated. It may be used for
>   programs and data that are shareable amongst a group of hosts, but not
>   found in /usr.
>
> Locally installed software must be placed within /usr/local rather
>   than /usr unless it is being installed to replace or upgrade software
>   in /usr.

As a general rule of thumb, in modern Linux distributions, software that is managed by the distributions package manager uses `/usr/bin` etc., while `/usr/local/bin` is used by local installations of software that is *not* managed by the package manager. The typical case here is software that is installed via `make, make install`. Static stand-alone binaries also fall into that category.

Another possibility is `/opt`. The division between `/opt` and `/usr/local` is not clear, but `/usr/local` is more customary for local installations. Here is what the FHS says about `/opt`:[/opt : Add-on application software packages](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_2.3/fhs-2.3.html#OPTADDONAPPLICATIONSOFTWAREPACKAGES).

Comment: Thanks. I created a folder under `/usr/local`, moved the binary to there and added the path to `$PATH`.

Comment: @sree you should not need to add `/usr/local/bin` to PATH. It should already be there. Here is my PATH (on Debian wheezy). It is `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`. I think that is the Debian default.

Comment: What I did was I created a folder `/usr/local/phantom-xx-6.x` and added `/usr/local/phantom-xx-6.x/bin to $PATH. Yes, /usr/local/bin is already in the $PATH.

Comment: @sree You could just put the binary in `/usr/local/bin`.

Answer (score 1):

If it is only used by a local user then I think that there is no point in keeping it in /usr/bin. This also makes it safer to access.

Link posted by you also says that it is as per FHS  (Filesystem Hierarchy Standard).